# I had my question marked as duplicate by people who don't know the technology. How do I dispute?

Tags: discussion

My [question about use of ramjets for second stage](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18207/why-is-conventional-ramjet-not-used-for-2nd-stage-of-rocket-propulsion) of rocket launch was tagged as duplicate by several users, and subsequently marked as duplicate. I found no way to dispute that (I edited the post, although I think that is unnecessary for people who understand the fundamental technical differences between different types of jet engines), but "duplicate" mark still persists.

Is there a way to "officially" request a review, or should I post new question (and risk be tagged as duplicate again by over-confident readers)?

Comment: I was one of the close voters, but for another reason (it was at first not entirely clear what you where asking, but that is fixed.) However, the close reason is chosen among the majority, and it seems like they thought it was a duplicate. In my opinion it is not, so I am going to give you a reopen vote.

Comment: You did the right thing: edit the post, respond to comments, and post on Meta. And your question is now reopened.